# How to create multiple collections and send posts dynamically in mongodb / mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Basically I am trying to make a to-do-app which will be based on the CITY that a user submits from, if they submit from VANCOUVER, then I want there to be a collection created named VANCOUVER and the post to be submitted there, then I can collect posts from that collection, the reason being performance when I begin to add query , so I dont have to query alot of the posts if I just need info from 1 city.

I did read the docs and current I am experimenting, would love some input here.

If someone can point me to some articales or guides / good doc points, I would love that or just help me if I am going the right way , or perhaps I should be looking at the problem in a different light?

This is my current route file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Schema import
const postModel = require('../models/postModel');

const vancouver = require('../models/cityModel');
const toronto = require('../models/cityModel');
const victoria = require('../models/cityModel');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// this should return all of the posts inside of a single city
// wildcard could be vancouver or toronto for example

router.get('/:wildcard', (req, res, next) => {
    req.params.wildcard.find((error, returnedDocuments) => {
        if (error) return next(error);
        res.json(returnedDocuments);
    });
});

// this should delete a single post, via an ID identification , inside of a specific city
// the city will be set on the user side

router.delete('/:wildcard', (req, res, next) => {
    req.params.wildcard.findByIdAndRemove(req.query.postid, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
        if (error) return next(error);
        res.json(returnedDocuments);
    });
});

router.post('/:wildcard', (req, res, next) => {
    req.body.wildcard.create({ post: req.body.post }, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

the city mode is basically just the city name, and has an array for posts, these will be queried based on the category that the user wants to access

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
        posts: { type: Array }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('city', citySchema);
```

Comment: Are you using some express middleware not mentioned here? I am asking because it seems you are using `req.params.wildcard` as though it is a mongo collection or mongoose Model, but I would expect this to be a string in vanila express.

Comment: well that would become vancouver or whatever city is requested no? if wildcard is VANCOUVER then it would correspond to the vancouver string of the model bound to that var

Comment: Unless I am missing something entirely, `req.params.wildcard` would be the string `"VANCOUVER"` in your example. To get the mongoose Model, you need to access the variable `vancouver` from line 7. A way to do this could be to put all your city-models in a hashmap (or simple object) with the city name as key and index it based on `req.params.wildcard`. Is the currently posted code working?

Comment: BTW requiring the same file multiple times on lines 7-9 is not going to get you new collections in the underlying mongodb, it will all go into the collection "city".

Comment: how can I go about creating those collections for my requirements? Should I hardcode 1 city and copy pasta it 15 times then simply query them using req.params.wildcard depending on the frontend what it needs? I am trying to keep it simple as I will have categories inside the city, like Jobs:{array} etc. then I will query them as needed

Comment: You could parameterize the call to `mongoose.model`. E.g. instead of exporting the model (in your second file), you export the citySchema. From your main file you instantiate the model based on the schema and the wildcard - you might need to cache the models so you don't instatiate the same multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the model-generation:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Schema import
const postModel = require('../models/postModel');

const citySchema = require('../models/citySchema');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getModel = (name) => mongoose.modelNames().contains(name) ? mongoose.model(name, citySchema) : mongoose.model(name)

router.get('/:wildcard', (req, res, next) => {
    // You should add some validation on the wildcard before using it directly here
    getModel(req.params.wildcard).find((error, returnedDocuments) => {
        if (error) return next(error);
        res.json(returnedDocuments);
    });
});

// ...

module.exports = router;
```

citySchema:

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
        posts: { type: Array }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

module.exports = citySchema;
```

A thing to note is that you are risking creating arbitrarily many models and collections, which might have some performance impact as well.

Comment: if  I am creating a seperate collection for vancouver_category1_Posts and toronto_category1_Posts etc, you feel this will have a performace impact? I think its pretty efficent, to create a seperate collection for each different city and the different topic, do you feel this is the way to go?  If I have 10 cateogry and 10 city, it will be 100 seperate collections, should be damn easy for mongodb to search 1 out of 100 to find data, very efficent

Comment: It depends on the expected number of categories and cities. If you only expect 10 cities and 10 categories, then no, I don't think it will be a problem - assuming you don't have too many cross-category and cross-city queries. As an alternative you might want to investigate simply having one collection and using indexes on a city-property and category-attribute.

Comment: every collection will be 100% stand alone, it is a no-frills posting app for many city, just to 'get the job done'  , I wont be doing complex query across city, perhaps I will do sorting query for specific city, but this should work in my favour as all the posts for that city are combined, and i dont need to worry about 90% of the data